# Multiple partial views on one main asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, repository, partial-views, irepository

trying to put a strongly typed partial view on a homepage in asp.net but it wont seem to work it, here is my code

new to asp.net and partial views.

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult VenuePartial()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = _entities.VenuePartialList();
        return View();
    }
```

Repository :

```
    public IEnumerable<Venue> VenuePartialList()
    {
        var list = from s in _entities.Venue
                   orderby s.name ascending
                   select s;
        return list.ToList();
    }
```

IRepository :

```
    IEnumerable<Venue> VenuePartialList();
```

Index Page :

```
   <%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Venue/VenuePartial.ascx");%>
```

Any help would be grateful asap please
regards T

Comment: Is your partial view `VenuePartial` a strongly type partial of `IEnumerable<Venue>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to pass a model to this partial:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Venue/VenuePartial.ascx", ViewData["Message"]); %>
```

And by the way WTF are you using `ViewData["Message"]` to pass a model instead of using a model and a strongly typed view:

```
public ActionResult VenuePartial()
{
    return View(_entities.VenuePartialList());
}
```

and then:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Venue/VenuePartial.ascx", Model); %>
```

This obviously assumes that your partial is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<Venue>`. If it is typed to a single `Venue` you might also consider using [Editor/Display Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450.aspx). So in your main view:

```
<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

and in the corresponding display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Venue.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.Venue>" %>
<span>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfVenue) %>
</span>
```

and now the display template will be rendered for each item of the model collection.

Comment: sorry I am new to this so putting ViewData["Message"] was obv wrong.    Do you mean put both of them in the code to make it work or just one of them : <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Venue/VenuePartial.ascx", ViewData["Message"]); %>   or  <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Venue/VenuePartial.ascx", Model); %>    or both?

Comment: @Trev, oops sorry then. It's normal if you are new to MVC. Even *old* guys to MVC make the same mistake and use `ViewData` so don't worry. And yes both are equivalent. It's just that you shouldn't use `ViewData`.

Comment: Yes it is strongly typed for the partial view.   I have put <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Venue/VenuePartial.ascx", Model); %>, now I get this error message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object. which is in reference to <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>, is this makin progess